# How to limit the size of core dump file when generating it using GDB

Tags: linux, gdb, arm, embedded-linux, coredump

I am running an embedded application on ARM9 board, where total flash size is 180MB only. I am able to run `gdb`, but when I do

`(gdb) generate-core-dump`

I get an error

```
warning: Memory read failed for corefile section, 1048576 bytes at 0x4156c000.
warning: Memory read failed for corefile section, 1048576 bytes at 0x50c00000.
Saved corefile core.5546
The program is running.  Quit anyway (and detach it)? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
Tamper Detected
**********OUTSIDE ifelse 0*********
length validation is failed
```

I also set `ulimit -c 50000` but still the core dump exceeds this limit. When I do `ls -l` to check file size it is over 300 MB. In this case how should I limit the size of core dump?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GDB does not respect 'ulimit -c', only the kernel does.

It's not clear whether you run GDB on target board, or on a development host (and using gdbserver on target). You probably should use the latter, which will allow you to collect full core dump.

Truncated core dumps are a pain anyway, as often they will not contain exactly the info you need to debug the problem.

Comment: I am running gdb on the target board. I can also use gdbserver, but since the crash is not easily reproducible, I am going with the first option.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see how running gdb or gdbserver as anything to do with the crash being easily reproducible or not ?

Comment: @shodanex - using the client-server model the core can be collected on the "host" file system, not on the embedded system, which here only has 180MB of available space for a core file. Presumably the host system has a full HDD, and is able to save a much bigger core file.

Answer (score 4):

in your shell rc-file:

```
limit coredumpsize 50000             # or whatever limit size you like
```

that should set the limit for everything, including GDB

Note:

If you set it to 0 , you can make sure your home directory is not cluttered with core dump files.

Answer (score 0):

When did you use ulimit -c ? It must be used before starting the program for which you're generating a core dump, and inside the same session.

Comment: I had set ulimit before running GDB. I have put 'ulimit -c 50000' in /etc/rc.d/init.d/startup and I checked manually also using 'ulimit -a' and it was set properly.