# How can I optimise core dump file size?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, embedded, coredump

I want to generate core dump files for my big C application on my embedded system running Linux. If I set

```
 ulimit -c unlimited
```

I get big dump files around 100Mb. This is too much in my case because my system is restarted if my application crash and the core is not fully generated. Moreover, it is more difficult to manipulate (to zip or so).

I don't think I need the whole memory dump I just want to see where my crash is when I have one. So I only need the stack and the heap I guess...

If I set

```
ulimit -c 1024
```

What data will I loose ?

On the core(5) manpage they explain how we can set a mask to select the data to dump :

```
       bit 0  Dump anonymous private mappings.
       bit 1  Dump anonymous shared mappings.
       bit 2  Dump file-backed private mappings.
       bit 3  Dump file-backed shared mappings.
       bit 4 (since Linux 2.6.24)
              Dump ELF headers.
       bit 5 (since Linux 2.6.28)
              Dump private huge pages.
       bit 6 (since Linux 2.6.28)
              Dump shared huge pages.
```

Maybe there is an optimisation there?

Thanks!

Comment: Well you seem to have found something worth trying. Did it not work?

Comment: Well I ran some tests. if I set small core dump file size like ulimit -c 1024
Sometimes I get errors like this in GDB:
Cannot access memory at address 0x80537244

Comment: Similar query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737465/how-to-limit-the-size-of-core-dump-file-when-generating-it-using-gdb

Comment: _Well I ran some tests_ ... and what did you the `coredump_filter` to? And what happened? And, what types of mapping do you have, and what do you need to debug?

Comment: Only with ulimit -c 1024 the core dump is not complete and I get "cannot access memory at address 0xXX with GDB".

I'm playing with coredump_filter right now. It seems that I have useless cores with the flag at 0x2. And exploitable, but big cores with 0x1.

I want to debug random crashes of a big enbedded application. I want to allow non technical people who are testing the software with me to send the core by email.