# What is a core dump file?

Tags: coredump

When I run a job using Slurm via `sbatch`, sometimes it generates a file with a filename like `core.12345` (with a different 5-digit string at different times). I could not find any documentation about what this file does and why it's generated, but there are some [mentions](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurmctld.html#lbAF) of it in the docs.

What does this file do and why is it generated? (Is it even being generated by Slurm or is this something else?)

Is there a way to suppress it from being generated? (It's quite big, on the order of several gigabytes, and automatically writes to my home directory on the cluster)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The core dump files are not generated by Slurm, but by the operating system. They keep the memory record of a process that have crashed.

They can be used for tracing the execution or debugging.

You can adjust the core dump file size including this command in your `.bashrc`:

> limit coredumpsize 2500

More info:

[Limit the size of a core dump file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737465/how-to-limit-the-size-of-core-dump-file-when-generating-it-using-gdb)

[Core dump file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump)